# Compare list of parameters with values

Tags: python

I would like to create a simple py script for validation list of parameters with specified value.

For example:

```
param1 - value1
param2 - value2
param3 - value3
```

Params can be printed from console in randomly sequence.
Value will be always the same. 
Should I create a list of params and assign the values for them?
How to start? What is the best method for newbie?

Comment: are you talking about functions parameters or something else?

Comment: random parameter with assign value, script should search each of param in input file and compare value

Comment: This is very unclear. Please read [ask].

Comment: Try python `dict` with `key` as `param` and `value` as `parameter`

Comment: I will try with pyhon map

Comment: If by python map you mean the `map` function then your last comment doesn't seem related to your question.